# UIAlertView Dialog results EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, exc-bad-access

I am trying to have an UIAlertView with two options like "YES" and "NO" in my XML parsing class. After I click one of the option I just get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Here is my code:

.m file:

```
  -(void)doneParsing 
  {
            UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                                              message:@"Do you want to continue?"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"No", @"Yes", nil];
            [myAlert show];
    }

 -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"user pressed Button Indexed 0");
            // Any action can be performed here
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"user pressed Button Indexed 1");
            // Any action can be performed here
        }
  }
```

.h file

```
@interface ArsivNoCheck : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

stack trace:

```
Stack trace : (
    0   TPAO Arastirma                      0x0006de86 -[ArsivNoCheck doneParsing] + 486
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014ae6b0 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    2   Foundation                          0x00eda765 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 327
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01f3bf3f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01f3b96f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 239
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x01f5e734 __CFRunLoopRun + 964
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x01f5df44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x01f5de1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    8   GraphicsServices                    0x021f07e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
    9   GraphicsServices                    0x021f0668 GSEventRun + 104
    10  UIKit                               0x003deffc UIApplicationMain + 1211
    11  TPAO Arastirma                      0x0000244d main + 141
    12  TPAO Arastirma                      0x00002375 start + 53
)
```

bt result

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x014ac09b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 15, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xe13e9e76)
    frame #0: 0x014ac09b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 15
    frame #1: 0x007d20bc UIKit`-[UIAlertView(Private) _buttonClicked:] + 294
    frame #2: 0x014ae705 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    frame #3: 0x003e22c0 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    frame #4: 0x003e2258 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    frame #5: 0x004a3021 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    frame #6: 0x004a357f UIKit`-[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
    frame #7: 0x004a26e8 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
    frame #8: 0x00411cef UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 846
    frame #9: 0x00411f02 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
    frame #10: 0x003efd4a UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
    frame #11: 0x003e1698 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
    frame #12: 0x021f1df9 GraphicsServices`_PurpleEventCallback + 339
    frame #13: 0x021f1ad0 GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 46
    frame #14: 0x01f2dbf5 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    frame #15: 0x01f2d962 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    frame #16: 0x01f5ebb6 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2118
    frame #17: 0x01f5df44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #18: 0x01f5de1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #19: 0x021f07e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
    frame #20: 0x021f0668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #21: 0x003deffc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
    frame #22: 0x0000204d TPAO Arastirma`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff394) + 141 at main.m:16
    frame #23: 0x00001f75 TPAO Arastirma`start + 53
```

Comment: At the error description there should be a class name of deallocated object, it is probably `ArsivNoCheck` (you've released delegating object).

Comment: provide the stack trace

Comment: I have added the stack trace.

Comment: Which object is actually giving the bad access? If you run it in the simulator, wait for the crash, then inspect each object using the debugger that should tell you which one it is.

Comment: @A-Live: That was my thought too, probably the delegate getting released - but if that was the case, I'd expect the stack trace to end in the delegate method (or just before the delegate method gets called, in UIKit)...

Comment: Add '[myAlert release];' after show, but this may not solve the problem.

Comment: @lykant: I cant release since I dont use ARC.

Comment: @DavidDoyle: since it is EXC_BAD_ACCESS I cant see which object and there is no error code. It crushes just after I click yes or no. So I cant put a breakpoint in clickedButtonAtIndex method.

Comment: now this error is being thrown in some other UIAlertView display in different classes. Don't understand why.

Comment: Ah-ha ... that means that A-Live's hypothesis is probably correct, the Alert View is trying to send the delegate message to the delegate which has already been released. This means that your delegate, assuming its a view controller, is not living long enough to handle the delegate method.

Comment: So what to do? Im really confused..

Comment: @gbesler run the app with Xcode, reproduce the error, type `bt` at console and post the result here.

Comment: @gbesler Basically, you need to find why your controller is getting released. Put a breakpoint in the controllers dealloc method, and find why it's being deallocated early.

Comment: @A-Live I have posted bt result. Sorry for being late..

Comment: @gbesler when is doneParsing called? i am sure it is being called earlier that is the reason alertview is giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: I have solved! I will post the solution in new message.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ARC?
This code is working fine, problem must be somewhere else.
But if you have button with No set it as cancel button

```
UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                                  message:@"Do you want to continue?"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
```

Comment: didn't help..still EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[myAlert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; instead
```

of  `[myAlert show];`

Comment: @gbesler, then i don't think your app crashed because of alert view. The issue may be different.

Answer (score 0):

Use following line of code-

```
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"Your Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
      [alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```